# How to interpret graphical confidence interval of regression line

Tags: confidence-interval

I would like to know if there is a way to interpret the confidence interval of a regression line in order to have an idea about the significance of the slope (so about the significance of the linear relationship between x and y ).

As a an exemple:

```
data(mtcars)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=qsec, y=mpg))+ 
geom_point()+
geom_smooth(method="lm")+
coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,50))
```

[image]

Just looking at the plot, is it possible to have an idea about the significance of the slope ? If yes, what is the rule ?

Thanks in advance.